# aodh-api service not getting installed after devstack installation

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install aodh. I am following this tutorial - https://docs.openstack.org/aodh/stein/install/install-ubuntu.html

When I run this command

```
aodh alarm list
```

I'm getting following error.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
  The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.


 </body>
</html> (HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-9f8035a5-e324-4e2f-b3f0-037b68f88d1a)
```

Even though the error says keystone is unavailable, I highly suspect that already there was some problem with aodh installation.

From the aodh link above, I in the final step, it says:
Restart the Alarming services:

```
# service aodh-api restart
# service aodh-evaluator restart
# service aodh-notifier restart
# service aodh-listener restart
```

When I tried this

```
service aodh-api restart
```

I got following error

```
Failed to restart aodh-api.service: Unit aodh-api.service not found.
```

Moreover in step 2 of above link
Source the admin credentials to gain access to admin-only CLI commands:

```
$ . admin-openrc
```

Since, I was unable to find admin-openrc, I skipped that step.

So, I am thinking probably aodh installation didn't go well. Hence the aforementioned error in 'aodh alarm list' command.

Other commands like 'nova list' etc are running fine

Can someone please help in figuring out, what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install aodh component as plugin during devstack installation.

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/116895/how-to-configure-devstack-with-ceilometer-gnocchi-and-aodh-components/

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encountered this problem, which has been answered on the official website.
https://docs.openstack.org/aodh/latest/contributor/install/index.html

Default, API is provided by apache2 wsgi.
But in my environment, this method can not successfully.
Another method, remove aodh apache2 wsgi, and create aodh-api service.
this method success.